# Unable to send notification from controller using signalr

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to send Some data/notification to my Angular client from .net core controller when an event is fired. I am using signalr to do this. but i am unable to recieve notification on my client. Can someone please guide me on what might be the problem.

Angular Component

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    this._hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
       .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
       .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/message", this.transportType)
       .build();
}

form() {
    this._hubConnection.on("Send", (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        that.disabled = false;
    });

    this._hubConnection.start()
        .then(() => console.log('connected'))
        .then(() => this._hubConnection.stop())
        .then(() => console.log('Disconnected'))
        .catch(e => console.error(e.message));
}
```

Controller

```
public class DataController : Controller
{
    private IHubContext<DataHub> _hubContext;

    public DataController(IHubContext<DataHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    private void OnProvideData(DataAndHeader data)
    {
        // server side code
        var data = "1234"
        _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", data);
    }
}
```

SignalR Hub

```
public class DataHub : Hub { }
```

I want to write the data from server side on client console.

Comment: When is `form()` called? Can you see in your console log that it has printed `connected`?

Comment: Yes. **connected** is logged successfully.  I would like to know why i am unable to log **data** when connection is on.

Comment: What triggers `OnProvideData`?

Comment: It is a method triggered when web server receives a response from an external server.

Comment: Just after you have printed 'connected' you close the connection again. Remove the call to `stop()`.

Comment: I did it. still no response from __hubconnection.on_.

Comment: Inspect the network traffic - if it's being transmitted or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. It is problem with _stop()_ method of hubconnection.

Comment: Why are you doing this way? There is no logic calling the start and then the stop hub method. You can POST on your controller to broadcast the received data to your SignalR clients but what you want to do is unclear.